# Boot system security

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows, hard-drive, lts

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + Windows 7 & 10 on 3 hard drives and would like to have one boot system yet am mildly security conscious:

- Will using the Ubuntu graphical interface GRUB 2 boot fixer with a view to loading Ubuntu 'OR' either Windows system affect the security of the Windows 7 & 10 systems, as in can the Linux part be used to place root kits etc. in them?

Comment: Linux(ubuntu) is more secure than windows.

Comment: Most of us, who dual boot or multiboot Ubuntu installed alongside other operating systems use the grub bootloader and the grub menu to boot into the operating systems. I think grub is good enough for this purpose and use it myself in this way.

Comment: if other people have access to the machine; ensure you put a password on grub.  it both hides detail about system (viewable the moment someone presses <e> etc) and stops some bypasses available via edit.     my 2c says its superior to windoze7 (for w7 you need to secure the power-cable/switch!)....

Answer (score 5):

> affect the security of the Windows 7 & 10 systems

Only if someone has access to your system. Physical access to a machine means that person has control over the machine and can do anything. Format the disks, install rootkits, keyloggers. Anything.

> as in can the Linux part be used to place root kits etc in them?

Yes, but Windows will the entry point for malware, not Ubuntu/Linux. In Ubuntu/Linux there are a few simple rules:

- A good admin password
- Create backups.
- Stick to official sites to install software, don't install software you do not use
- Don't install software to access your system remotely

... and it is impossible for someone other than you to install a root kit.

It is very easy to install a root kit when you have physical access. You can reboot Ubuntu/Linux and you can use an live session to install software onto the system. Remotely that is very hard to pull off.

---

The entry points into Ubuntu/Linux are WINE, samba shares, connection software into your system (remote desktop), software installed from unofficial sites.

(all of these require admin password; so use a good one).

And then the more unlikely methods ... bugs in browsers, deliberate bugs in encryption tools, or openSSL (NSA) a breached repository, hacked websites where someone altered ISO's and the hashes for those ISOs (Mint with their wordpress site).

(these... well we need to trust someone. Canonical has a good track record; they have yet to admit to something related to a breach that impacted us all where they where the responsible party. Their track record is better than Microsoft or Apple, and better than the maintainers of Mint).